# Returning the value to input

Tags: javascript, html

From input i enter numbers in the input text, then i have 5 buttons that have functions on them i tried to make the first button to minus the number by 1 but i don't know when i click the number get -1 but it doesn't show changes to the input box. How can i fix this i mean don't know how to do it because i tried using `number.innerHTML = number-=1` but it doesn't work ? Here is my html and javascript code:

```js
var number = document.getElementById("number");
number = number.value;

function minus() {
  number.value = number -= 1;
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="number" id="output">
    <input type="button" value="<" onclick="minus();">
    <input type="button" value=">" onclick="plus();">
    <input type="button" value="FLIP" onclick="flip();">
    <input type="button" value="STORE" onclick="store();">
    <input type="button" value="CHECK" onclick="check();">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok let's think logically here

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");
number = number.value;

function minus() {
  number.value = number -= 1;
  console.log(number);
}
```

first you're assigning the HTML ELEMENT itself to the var "number", then you're changing the value of the "number" var to the **value** of the HTML element, so then `number.value = number - 1` is trying to set the property of "value" of a number object, which doesn't make sense, because it's not connected to the HTML element anymore

Just make *two* variables it should be fine, like

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var numberValue = number.value;

function minus() {
  numberValue = number.value;
  number.value = numberValue -= 1;
  console.log(number,numberValue);
}
```

or alternatively, you only need one variable total, and you don't need to reassign it to "number.value", but the only thing is that this way there's no guarantee that number.value is a number at all, but when you set it to a variable first, like above, you can check `if(!isNaN)` or something similar, but still, if we want to assume only numbers will ever be entered, we can do something like

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");


function minus() {

  number.value = number.value -= 1;
  console.log(number,number.value);
}
```

Comment: Almost there, you're subtracting the initial value each time you click on the minus button. It should be : 

var number = document.getElementById("number");

function minus() {
  number.value = number.value -= 1;
}

Comment: @Lka right lol dind't think of that...

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead.

```js
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function minus() {
  number.value = number.value -= 1;
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="number" id="output">
    <input type="button" value="<" onclick="minus();">
    <input type="button" value=">" onclick="plus();">
    <input type="button" value="FLIP" onclick="flip();">
    <input type="button" value="STORE" onclick="store();">
    <input type="button" value="CHECK" onclick="check();">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```